# Can I use a Mobile Passport receipt with Global Entry?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, mobile-apps, global-entry

I've just applied for Global Entry but am having second thoughts. But I've configured Mobile Passport on my phone, and now I'm wondering what the best approach is to expediting the US entry process (as a US citizen). I'm not clear on exactly how the stages in Global Entry and Mobile Passport play out, but in thinking through what I've managed to gather, it seems to come down to whether, having arrived at the airport and had a look at the lines, I can easily choose between Global Entry and the Mobile Passport line. And whether that's convenient boils down to whether the Mobile Passport receipt I've generated can be used in the Global Entry line, or whether, in order to preserve the option to choose at the airport, I'd need to fill out both the Mobile Passport form, and the paper form.

So the key question is: Can I use a Mobile Passport receipt with Global Entry?

Comment: FWIW, [I already have TSA Pre✓](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/88511/1607), so that's not a factor in determining whether to get GE.

Comment: You don't need to fill out a paper form if you're using Global Entry; instead, you make your declaration at the kiosks.

Comment: @waiwai933: So I can skip the paper form either way: quickly do the Mobile Passport form on the plane (if I choose), and then decide at the airport whether to go through GE or MP? I guess a critical part of getting a full answer is: does generating a MP receipt that I don't use (e.g., if I go through GE instead) [create any issues or confusions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/88515/1607).

Comment: I'll just say that I travel a fair bit, but I've not yet been to an airport where there was a queue at the Global Entry machines, even when there was a huge crowd in the main part of the arrivals hall. With GE you only deal with the machine, there's generally no need to talk to a human so there's no queue after the machine. I predict that if you get GE you won't care much about other options unless you are traveling with someone who has to go the other way.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Global Entry, you don't need any paperwork (you answer the questions at the kiosk), and I've never seen a line at Global Entry.

I haven't tried mobile passport, but it looks appropriate if, say, you're traveling with your family and they don't all have GE.

If you plan to travel internationally often, GE is great, and IME reliably the fastest way through entry.