# Any problem with starting Global Entry & TSA Precheck application at the same time?

Tags: global-entry, tsa-precheck

I know there's another [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88511/what-happens-to-an-existing-tsa-precheck-registration-if-i-apply-for-global-entr) that might look like my question, but mine is asking having 2 applications starting at the same time.

I started my global entry application this week as I have quite a few domestic trips coming up and a couple international at the end of the year. Due to the fact that CBP officers have been sent to the southern border, global entry applications have been pushed and there's a big delay in processing as well as scheduling for an interview.

I'm planning to apply for a TSA Precheck as it can be obtained within a few weeks, and there are many enrollment centers as well. I guess since they're two separate programs, there won't be any conflict, but I would like to hear from anyone with experience in this. Thank you.

Comment: Note that a Global Entry number will get you TSA Pre endorsement on your boarding passes, but maybe you don't want to wait. Also, at SFO (and some other airports), once your application has preliminary approval there you can finish Global Entry airside (coming off a plane) without appointment.

Comment: True. However, Interview on arrival only apply for international arrivals, and my international trips are after my domestic trips so that doesn't help. One thing is that I don't pay for all of the application fees, that's why I don't mind apply for both.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you are okay with two separate background checks and paying twice for the service,  you should be fine.

According to [this article](https://upgradedpoints.com/global-entry-program-frequently-asked-questions):

> ### 12. What is TSA PreCheck and how is it different from Global Entry?
>
> TSA PreCheck is actually a separate program from Global Entry, but
>   because you’ve been through the rigorous background check of Global
>   Entry, TSA PreCheck is automatically given to you without any
>   additional fee.

Comment: I don't see that the excerpt (or anything else in the linked article) addresses the possibility of actually signing up for both services.

Comment: @NateEldredge it explains the difference of TSA Pre-check and Global Entry, in question 12 and it states that they are different things, with different background checks. It's in the center of the page if you scroll down.

Answer (score 3):

As far as the TSA is concerned, there’s no limit to how many Known Traveler Numbers you can have. For instance, military personnel who have Global Entry will have two (one for military, one for Global Entry) and can use either.